# Why does this regex not match as expect?

Tags: regex

https://regex101.com/r/hV6rA2/1

> Pattern : ^(\d{5})^\D{0,3}(\d{4})$

and

> Value   :  43234-3423

Why doesn't this match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(\d{5})\D{0,3}(\d{4})$
```

remove the second `^`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hV6rA2/3